# Ребят срочно..)мне нужно правило почему..

Tags: правописание

почему слово одн**О**временно пишется с о..

Answer (score 1):

Числительные один, тысяча, миллион, миллиард соединяются со второй частью слова с помощью соединительных гласных о, е, т.е. они функционируют как существительные: однодневный,одновременный, двадцатиодноведерный, миллионоголосый, миллиардофутовый, тысячелетний, тысячелетие

http://hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook051/01/part-005.htm